# Hystrix fallback method returns null

Tags: spring, microservices, hystrix, fallback, feign

I implemented feign client and hystrix to my spring boot microservice application.
I first tried to test to communicate `users service` to `albums service` with feign client,
so I threw an exception at `albums service` to check if `users service` Error Decoder can catch the exception and then make the fallback method triggered.

It worked, but the `cause` is always null only at the first time, and after that I can see the error message that I wanted to see.

Can anyone tell me if something is wrong or not.
This is my code.

1. Users Service Feign Client

```java
@FeignClient(name = "albums-ws", fallbackFactory = AlbumsFallbackFactory.class)
public interface AlbumServiceClient {

    @GetMapping(path = "users/{userId}/albums")
    List<AlbumDetailResponse> getAlbums(@PathVariable("userId") String userId);
}
```

2. Fallback Factory

```java
@Component
public class AlbumsFallbackFactory implements FallbackFactory<AlbumServiceClient> {

    @Override
    public AlbumServiceClient create(Throwable cause) {
        return new AlbumServiceClientFallback(cause);
    }
}
```

```java
public class AlbumServiceClientFallback implements AlbumServiceClient {

    private final Throwable cause;
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public AlbumServiceClientFallback(Throwable cause) {
        this.cause = cause;
    }

    @Override
    public List<AlbumDetailResponse> getAlbums(String userId) {
        logger.error("An exception took place: " + cause.getMessage());

        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

3. Feign Error Decoder

```java
@Component
public class FeignErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {

    @Override
    public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
        switch(response.status()) {
            case 400:
                break;

            case 404:
                if(methodKey.contains("getAlbums")) {
                    return new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.valueOf(response.status()), response.reason());
                }
                break;

            default:
                return new Exception(response.reason());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

4. First fallback triggered

```
2020-08-02 12:42:27.836 ERROR 24772 --- [ HystrixTimer-1] c.a.p.a.u.P.f.AlbumServiceClientFallback : An exception took place: null
```

5. After

```
2020-08-02 12:43:07.672 DEBUG 24772 --- [rix-albums-ws-2] c.a.p.a.u.P.feign.AlbumServiceClient     : [AlbumServiceClient#getAlbums] User not found with id: f5b313e2-411f-4fc3-95e7-9aa5c43c286c
```

Answer (score 0):

Hystrix has class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.HystrixTargeter. There is a comment in targetWithFallbackFactory method:

> We take a sample fallback from the fallback factory to check if it
> returns a fallback        that is compatible with the annotated feign
> interface.

and code after:

```
Object exampleFallback = fallbackFactory.create(new RuntimeException());
```

It is why you don't have cause in exception.